# How to delete data from MySQL using w/ Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, api

I'm currently working on a small assignment, building a CRUD app with mysql and reactjs.
I've got the Create and Read working okay, but I am having problems with update and delete.

my product elements with update and delete button. (Know update function is separate, I just happened to write delete in this file just for convenience for now).

I assumed that by being able to send in info.ProductID (which gets the selected product's unique ID), then sending it thru the deleteProduct(id) function, it should be deleted, but I seemed to maybe be missing something? The error isn't telling me so much: **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**

```
export default function Product({info}) {
    const { loggedIn, addToCart, cartItems, removeFromCart, openUpdateModal, updateModal, setUpdateModal } = useContext(Context);

    const deleteProduct = (id) => {
        fetch('http://localhost/phpTask/api/products/delete.php', {
            method: "DELETE",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                ProductID: id
            })
        }).then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
    }

    const heartIcon = () => {
        const alreadyHearted = cartItems.some(item => item.ProductID === info.ProductID)
        if(alreadyHearted) {
            return <i style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="fas fa-heart" onClick={() => removeFromCart(info)}></i>
        } else {
            return <i style={{cursor: "pointer"}} className="far fa-heart" onClick={() => addToCart(info)}></i>
        }
    }
  
    return (
        <div className="main-products-container">
            <p>Product ID: {<br/>} {info.ProductID}</p>
            <p>Category ID: {<br/>} {info.CategoryID}</p>
            <p>Product Name: {<br/>} {info.ProductName}</p>
            <p>Price: {<br/>} {info.Price}</p>
            {loggedIn ? 
                (   <>
                        <UpdateButton className="editBtn" onClick={openUpdateModal} />
                        <UpdateModal updateModal={updateModal} setUpdateModal={setUpdateModal} />
                        <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(info.ProductID)}>Delete</button>
                    </>
                ) : 
                (
                heartIcon()
                )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and this is my delete api (php):

```
<?php 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../../utils/Database.php';
include_once '../../models/Products.php';

//instantiate db object + connect

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

//instantiate product obj
$product = new Products($db);

//get raw product data
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//set ID to update
$post->ProductID = $data->$ProductID;

// delete product
if($product->deleteProduct()) {
    echo json_encode(
        array('message' => 'Product deleted')
    );
} else {
    echo json_encode(
        array('message' => 'Product not deleted')
    );
}

?>
```

and my public deleteProduct() function:

```
public function deleteProduct() {
            //create query
            $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE ProductID = :ProductID";
            //prepare statement
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
            //clean data
            $this->ProductID = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->ProductID));
            //bind data
            $stmt->bindParam(':ProductID', $this->ProductID);
            //execute
            if($stmt->execute()){
                return true;
            }
            //print error if something goes wrong
            printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
            return false;

        }
```

This is my first time setting up my own API, and I understand if there are lots of mistakes. If I could just be pointed at the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share some debugging info. Check the browsers network tab (in the browsers developer tools) while making the request to see exactly what the request looks like (is the id passed properly?) and what the response from the server is. The error you get is from your JS trying to parse the response as JSON while you get something else back (perhaps a PHP error message or something).

Comment: A note: When making a http request using the DELETE method, you usually pass the ID in the URL (part of the path `/api/items/1` or query param `/ap/items?id=1`) since the body in a DELETE request usually is ignored.

Comment: `$data->$ProductID;` should be `$data->ProductID;` (no $ in front of the property). You should also check if the data is valid and contains that property instead of just assuming. You also set it on `$post->ProductID` when your product instance is `$product` (`$post` would be undefined). If you check your web servers error log, you should see some errors in there that can guide you through all the issues. There's too much to go through here.

Comment: And this: `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->ProductID))` is _completely_ pointless. Just use the value as is. When using prepared statements, you don't need to manually escape or "clean" the data. And even if you needed to, those two functions would be the wrong ones to use anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the help Magnus. the typos cleared things up. It is deleting the selected product item, and now I just need to make it so that it returns the remaining object in order for me to change state to re-render w/o having to reload the page. Thank you again for your help! I'll read up more on prepared statements as well.

Comment: You're already using prepared statements properly, but it doesn't hurt to read up more about that subject so you understand what they do and why they are the best option to protect against SQL injections.